# ListBox items separator when more than one item

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ListBox and I'm trying to insert a separator between items but I want the separator to show when there is more than one item.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="WarningListBox" Visibility="Visible"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Warnings}">
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanShowAll}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="120"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource NewDesignListItemBoxStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TypeOneViewModel" DataType="{x:Type vm:TypeOneViewModel}">
            <notifications:TypeOneNotification Focusable="False" MinHeight="30" Background="Beige"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TypeTwoViewModel" DataType="{x:Type vm:TypeTwoViewModel}">
            <notifications:TypeTwoNotification Focusable="False" MinHeight="30" Background="Beige"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <templateSelectors:WarningTemplateSelector
            TypeOneDataTemplate="{StaticResource TypeOneViewModel}"
            TypeTwoDataTemplate="{StaticResource TypeTwoViewModel}"/>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
</ListBox>
```

I've tried adding the Separator right before the  closing tag
`<Separator Margin="30 0 30 0" BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" BorderThickness="2"/>`
but it crashes the application. Should I somehow put it in a DataTemplate? I think it will then show under each item (even when there's only one item).

Comment: Try with DataTrigger, and bindig to previousData, with seting FallBackValue

Comment: Or do you want to just show one separator, under first item where there is more then one item?

Comment: Do you want to hide the separator *only* when there is only one item? Is it OK if you have a separator below the last item when there are two or more items?

Comment: I want all items to be separated, ie the separator should be only between items. And no separator if there's just one item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you want to achieve something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TypeOneViewModel" DataType="{x:Type vm:TypeOneViewModel}">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Separator x:Name="separator" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Separator.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Separator">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}, FallbackValue={x:Null}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Separator.Style>
        </Separator>
        <!--Rest of your DataTemplate-->
        <notifications:TypeOneNotification Focusable="False" MinHeight="30" Background="Beige"/>
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

This will hide the separator, if item have no `PreviousData`, so for the 1st item.

You can easy take Separator style outside if used more then once, and just call it as StaticResource.

Comment: but where should I add this code? (sorry, I'm still a beginner wtih xaml)

Comment: @ValCool there, where you have your DataTemplates declararion, on both x:Key TypeOneViewModel, and TypeTwo